Точка вращения для спрайта BabylonJS
Недавно столкнулся с проблемой метода Pivot для спрайтов фрейма BabylonJS, его нет :D
Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с похожей проблемой и как всё-таки задать точку вращения для спрайта в BabylonJS. Главным требованием для метода должно быть именно вращение спрайта относительно какой-то точки в пространстве, как с методом center в ThreeJS, когда привязываешь спрайт к какой-то точке и задаёшь ему метод center в нескольких координатах от нужной точки.
